# How to pass server.{host,port} to grails under Eclipse/STS

Tags: eclipse, grails

I need to set grails.server.host and grails.server.port differently on different dev machines, or in different configurations. I can set them in BuildConfig.groovy but that is source-controlled so I don't want to check in machine-specific info there. How can I pass these from the Run Configuration?

I have tried every combination of -Dserver.host and -Dgrails.server.host, with the values in quotes or not, in the Arguments tab Program Arguments and VM Arguments fields, and just server.host or grails.server.host in the Environment tab; I even tried changing the Grails tab's Grails Command field to "-Dserver.host=192.168.2.110 run-app" but grails keeps coming up "localhost:8080"

My fallback is to try and set them with an external property file, but then I have to get fancy about setting them differently for different environments and such, and I don't have easy UI visibility like I do with the Run As ... menu. So, can someone tell me how they are configuring Eclipse/STS to pass a grails parameter?

(Using Eclipse (STS 2.7.1) with grails 2.0.0M1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-Dserver.host=192.168.2.110 -Dserver.port=8888` Should work if set in the VM arguments...

Have you tried `grails -Dserver.host=192.168.2.110 -Dserver.port=8888 run-app` from terminal or the command prompt?

Comment: I expected it would work in the VM args, but grails launch output still said "Browse to http://localhost" and so I thought my server.host assignment wasn't taking effect. Your suggestion made me go and actually try the assigned IP (192.168.2.110) and it works after all. Thanks!

Comment: I should record an error I was making: I put the two -D arguments on separate lines in the VM Arguments field (oops) - they need to be one line, just as @gotomanners indicated.